# Can this mySQL query be optimized better? Not a mySQL guru but I think I got it right

Tags: php, mysql

Basically, I have two tables that have a 1 to 1 relation.
When I delete a row from subset_panel_options I also want to delete the related row in subset_panel_options_list 

Here is some of structure for the two tables. There is no need to show the full table.

> [subset_panel_options]
>   ->id
>   ->subset_panel_id
>
> [subset_panel_options_list]
>   ->id
>   ->subset_panel_options_id

```
DELETE subset_panel_options, subset_panel_options_list 
FROM subset_panel_options 
JOIN subset_panel_options_list 
WHERE subset_panel_options.id = subset_panel_options_list.subset_panel_options_id 
AND subset_panel_id = $subsetPanelId
```

Comment: Are you using InnoDB? You could set "On Delete Cascade" and just do "DELETE subset_panel_options WHERE subset_panel_id = $subsetPanelId"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can:

```
DELETE FROM subset_panel_options 
LEFT JOIN subset_panel_options_list
ON (subset_panel_options.id = subset_panel_options_list.subset_panel_options_id)
WHERE subset_panel_options.subset_panel_id = $subsetPanelId
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` you ensure you are deleting from "subset_panel_options" even if there is no corresponding match in the subset_panel_options_list table.

---

You may also want use referential integrity features available in InnoDB engine. In this case, you need to define `subset_panel_options_id` as a FK (foreign key) in the `subset_panel_options_list` table, and an "ON DELETE CASCADE" constraint on it, meaning that when rows at `subset_panel_options` are deleted, the "orphan" rows in `subset_panel_options_list` should be immediately deleted too.